# How can I query the database culture (SQL Server 2005)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, culture

How can I query the database culture (SQL Server 2005) ?

I have problems inserting and getting dates, because the client's servers don't run on the same culture as my developer server.

I can adjust the date, but I need to know the server's culture...

Comment: I thought SQL Server took the culture info from the OS (assuming you are not talking about CLR queries)

Comment: Yes it does, but if the developer OS language is different from the server OS language, that creates problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find out about the currently configured language using this:

```
SELECT @@language
```

and you might also want to check out this:

```
EXEC sp_helplanguage
```

It will show the available languages, and what date formats etc. they have. This is basically the contents of the `sys.syslanguages` system catalog table.

As for date handling - preferably use DateTime based parametrized queries, or if you have to have date strings, use the [ISO-8601 date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in SQL Server.

The format  `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS`  will always work, regardless of currently selected language settings in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need that.

- Dates as DATES always get input/ouput in the client, the server culture is irrelevant here as the visualization / string conversion happens on the client. So, use variables foe query parameters and get the proper types as output (should happen autoamtically) and you will not have a problem to start with.
- If you have to insert strings, use ISO form (2010-12-05 23:15:22.233) which is recognized under ALL culture settings as generic fallback.