# C# With SQLite, real with comma on value how to get it?

Tags: c#, sqlite, compact-framework

on the SQLite have a table with several column with real, if the value of real as a dot on it ex `123.23` I can get this value without any problem with `reader["columnname"].ToString();`

But when the value of the column is as `123,23` if I try to get it it will come as 0

I did double check the value and its there but allways come as 0.

How I can read this properly?!

Edit:

Code where I'm reading the query

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Ajuda_Compras WHERE Cod_Art = @prodCod";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodCod", value);
    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ManagerLastPrices tempLast;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tempLast = new ManagerLastPrices();
            tempLast.ProdCod = reader["Cod_art"].ToString();
            tempLast.Descr = reader["Descricao"].ToString();
            tempLast.Date = reader["Data"].ToString();
            tempLast.FiscalYear = reader["AnoFiscal"].ToString();
            tempLast.DocType = reader["TipoDoc"].ToString();
            tempLast.Serie = reader["Serie"].ToString();
            tempLast.DocNumber = reader["N_Doc"].ToString();
            tempLast.Qtd = reader["Qtd"].ToString();
            tempLast.DiscountPrice = reader["P_Compra"].ToString();
            tempLast.DiscountPerc = reader["Desc1"].ToString();
            tempLast.Price = reader["P_Unit"].ToString();
            tempLast.EntityID = reader["Id_Terceiro"].ToString();
            tempLast.Entity = reader["Terceiro"].ToString();
            this._listLastPrices.Add(tempLast);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of your issue?

Comment: Sure a sec I will edit the OP

Comment: Done, for example, the Qtd value is real, but the value comes as `123.23` it can read it without any problem but on P_Compra and on P_unit the values comes with a comma and not a dot, it comes as 0

Comment: Will the P_Compra and P_unit values have a set format? Eg: The format of P_Compra will be ##,## and say P_unit will be ###,###? Or will they be varied?

Comment: they can be from 2 to 4 decimal digits

Comment: Database stores value with cultureinfo defined for the DB (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432185/how-can-i-query-the-database-culture-sql-server-2005). You can format a string using different cultureInfo (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx). I wonder why it stores values with different cultureinfo in same table. Possibly you can show the table scheme. Qtd and the other num fields seem to have different definition.

Answer (score 1):

> If your datatype is double your code as given below.
>   You can use [`SqliteDataReader.GetDouble(colIndex)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getdouble?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteDataReader_GetDouble_System_Int32_) to get the column index use [`SqliteDataReader.GetOrdinal(colname)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getordinal?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0)

EG:

```
double temp= reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("P_Compra"));
tempLast.DiscountPrice = temp.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: if I do the `double temp= Convert.ToDouble(reader["P_Compra"]);`the temp it will have `0.0` as value

Comment: @Camadas are you sure there are values in your table? if yes can you post the screen shot of the avail data here ? because if the table has values then the Convert.ToDouble will give the correct results

Comment: Yep like I told u 100% sure, like I told at the beguining, here is the pic https://imgur.com/a/9RzvszZ

Comment: Even if I change the query to `cmd.CommandText = "Select Cod_Art, Descricao, Data, AnoFiscal, TipoDoc, Serie, N_Doc, Qtd, Desc1, Id_Terceiro, Terceiro," +
    " replace(P_Unit,',','.') as P_Unit, replace(P_Compra,',','.') as P_Compra from Ajuda_Compras where Cod_Art = @prodCod";` I will get the values only with `reader["P_Compra"].ToString();` I will get the value correct but with a dot not comma, I can allways convert it later

Comment: then you can use my answer's approach too but your value is 0,179 & 0,198

Comment: Invalid cast, https://imgur.com/eKxvS3e, I did try that approach before asking here even did try the `reader.GetFloat....`

Comment: They buddy i think the data type of the column in data base should be your only solution.I think it is already string

Comment: That I don't know, for example the column that are Text AKA String, by getting them as `reader["ColumnName"].ToString()` it will read without any problem.

I will change the query to the one I did show on one of my comment here, that way it will replace the `,` with `.` and it can read it without any problems as `reader["P_Unit"].ToString()` then I just replace the dot with comma with `reader["P_Unit"].ToString.Replace('.', ',');`

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: Yes and no, when calling the `reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("P_Compra"));`it would come as 0 , did have to change it to the comment that I made to make it work

Comment: I would do it, but the main thing is with the solution provided if the value as a `,` and not a `.` it will be `0` and not `0.179` as it should be, did have to change the query and how to get it as `reader["P_Unit"].ToString().Replace('.', ',');`